# Why is Holy Quran in Arabic?

Tags: quran, arabic

The question is simple. Why is Quran in Arabic? There are many other languages besides Arabic, so why Arabic is selected specially by ALLAH SWT?

Comment: Why did you write this question in English? Maybe because English is the primary language of this site and post in, say, Swahili would be useless to the community here? Try extrapolating....

Comment: @Caleb so If the Quran had been given to a group of people other than Arabs, it would have been given in a different language? I'm not Muslim, but I think many Muslims would disagree. Islam holds Arabic as holy and superior to other languages. I think many might say that the Quran had to be in Arabic regardless of who it was revealed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question.

Quran was revealed in Arabic because:

- Prophet Muhammad (SAW) was Arab.
- The people who were the first recipients were Arabs.
- The language of people of many surrounding areas and countries around Makkah and Madinah was Arabic (different dialects).
- Arabic is *not* a [dead language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_death). From the time of Prophet (SAW) till today, there has always been a rich collection of literature in Arabic. It allows addition of new words and terms.